# Use of firebase functions when using firebase hosting locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I currently have my project setup with firebase functions being used for some of the backend functions.

I want to be able to test these functions locally when typing in `firebase serve` when I use the website, not querying the function using postman, for example.

Is there any way I can do this?

I've tried just typing in `firebase serve` but this gives me the functions that have been deployed to firebase, not the ones that I have changed locally.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Have you seen and followed this article which shows how to run your firebase functions locally? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: @Asdfg yup, I've tried `firebase emulators:start` but this does not work for the problem that I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that you use

`firebase.functions().useFunctionsEmulator('http://localhost:5001');`

to use locally hosted functions.